# Hash is different in SQL and C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

In my database I have SQL,

```
DECLARE @InputString nvarchar(15) ='pass'
DECLARE @InputSalt nvarchar(36) = 'FC94C37C-03A3-49A3-9B9F-D4A82E708618'

DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(100)
Declare @BinaryHash varbinary(max)
set @HashThis = @InputString + @InputSalt
set @BinaryHash= HASHBYTES('SHA1', @HashThis) 
SELECT CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@BinaryHash")))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

and C# I have,

```
public static string HashString(string cleartext)
{
    byte[] clearBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cleartext);
    return HashBytes(clearBytes);
}  

public static string HashBytes(byte[] clearBytes)
{
    var hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
    byte[] hashBytes =   hasher.ComputeHash(clearBytes);
    string hash = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    hasher.Clear();
    return hash;
}
HashString("passFC94C37C-03A3-49A3-9B9F-D4A82E708618")
```

But the hash is different?

```
C# Output: S55Nz1lyGweoJEHWcC6zFxJDKWQ=
SQL Output: 4jqyC1pLJ0hW+AMNk8GOWCC99KY=
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/4bwAtm

Comment: What is the output of both?

Comment: @CodeCaster, upated post

Comment: C# value (S55Nz1lyGweoJEHWcC6zFxJDKWQ=) seems to be the correct one for the input, need to fix SQL code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your hash function runs on bytes, not on characters. You effectively translate the characters to bytes, but you don't do it the same way in C# as you do in SQL: you use `nvarchar` (UTF-16) from SQL, you use UTF-8 from C#. You can change either to match the other.

Since you don't have any non-ASCII characters in your current test, for that particular password, you can easily verify that this is the problem by simply changing `nvarchar` to `varchar` in your SQL. This will not be sufficient for the full range of Unicode characters though.

Comment: OK Thanks How can I update C# code. I can't update the SQL because our existing system is based on this.

Comment: I have change UTF-8 to UTF-16, `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(cleartext);` and its working. Is this is a correct fix?

Comment: Its not working when we have arabic char. Please help me to fix this. i can only change C#